# ffmpeg images > video won't work

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So I'm trying to use ffmpeg to combine all my images into a video but i keep
getting a "could find no file with path" but I'm in the path powered directly
from the directory of it.

files are named as (img0046.png) and up but when I try to combine them into a video with this command it won't work.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

it will return as this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first number is `46`, use

```
ffmpeg -start_number 46 -i img%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```